# Blender interface/viewport lag

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I have recently upgraded to an Asus FX753V laptop but the blender interface and viewport movement lags badly compared to my lesser spec Dell laptop I used to have. I have the most recent NVIDIA drivers but can't get smooth operation.

Any suggestions or help  would be awesome!

The specs for my new Asus:
i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.8GHz
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050
16GB RAM
Solid State Drive

Comment: Is this behavior on the same scenes? The same display modes? What is your screen resolution now and before? I experienced the same "disappointment" when i got my new rig with a 1080 Ti until i realized i now had a 4k display in comparison to my FHD one before, so blender had to crunch 4x more pixels than before in the viewport.

Comment: It's a fresh install of blender and lags when I use the standard startup scene with the cube.

Comment: Ok well thats not expected then, something is definitely off here but im not sure if its Blender related at that point. Blender version 2.79?

Comment: It's very odd indeed, correct blender 2.79. On initial install blender didn't show the CUDA option in the system settings. I had to add a .dll file to the blender directory. I got it off a helpful guy on youtube which has allowed me the CUDA option but not sure if it's actually working.

Comment: Assuming you are on win 10, can you try and right-click your blender icon on the desktop and select "run with graphics processor" and then select the 1050Ti? it might be that blender is running with your integrated intel gfx card

Comment: Correct, I am running win10. Should there be a major difference in performance between running with 'intergrated graphics' or 'High performance Nvidia'? I've tried both and haven't notice much difference in the lag when moving the cube or rolling over the interface menus with the mouse

Comment: Yes, there should be a noticeable difference between integrated graphics and your dedicated gfx card.

Comment: Found the solution! I had to roll back to original nvidia driver for my graphics card, install the latest CUDA software and reinstall blender. Working like a dream. Thanks for taking the time to assist.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution! I had to roll back to original nvidia driver for my graphics card, install the latest CUDA software and reinstall blender. Working like a dream. Thanks for taking the time to assist.